# Handle Input Processor in Device Back Button and Button as Actor

Tags: libgdx

How to handle a event for both key as well as actor added in the screen? My problem is that at a time only one input processor is available either for button or device back button. How can I set input processor for both back button of device and button which act as actor on the screen.

I implemented following code for button input processor
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
button was added in the stage so I implement input processor for the stage.

For device back button
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
Register actor as input processor

In keyDown event I write 
if (keycode == Keys.ESCAPE || keycode == Keys.BACK)
    LevelLoadScreen.flagResume = true;

Other solution also acceptable if it handle both the action listener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question clearly. I'll assume the following:

- You got a Stage set as InputProcessor
- You got another special button as InputProcessor which you refer to as "device back button"
- You want them both to process input but it seems you can only set 1 InputProcessor at a time

If above is the case, then one way is to use an [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) which is apart of libgdx.

First, create an InputMultiplexer.

Then, set it as the InputProccessor.

Add your two InputProcessors to the InputMultiplexer: back button, then stage in this order.

- If you return **false** in back button event handlers, then the
  **event gets passed to** stage as well.
- If you return **true** in back button event handlers, then **events
  do not get raised** in stage.

Answer (score 3):

You have to overwrite the `keyDown` function in Stage.

See this example code

```
mStage = new Stage() {
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
            if (keyCode == Keys.BACK) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
            return super.keyDown(keyCode);
        }
    };
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mStage);
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
```